# How to make a UK date out of a standard date format string using sed?

Tags: sed

The string `Fri May  3 13:50:37 2013` has to be reorder to `Fri 3 May 2013 13:50:37`. How can this be achieved using `sed`?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What did you try in order to solve the problem?

Comment: Right now i have done it by c coding which does my job but i need to optimize my code and hopefully make it a oneliner:)

Comment: help me please @devnull....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` isn't the right tool here you want `awk`:

```
$ echo "Fri May 3 13:50:37 2013" | awk '{print $1,$3,$2,$5,$4}'
Fri 3 May 2013 13:50:37
```

In `awk` `$i` represents the i<sup>th</sup> field so just arrange the fields in the order required.

Comment: Isnt it possible using sed as i have a very tight resource system which only has sed.

Comment: Of course it is possible using `sed` but that doesn't make it right for the job. Why do you say you don't have `awk` in your comment on this answer but say you do have `awk` in the comment on @Kent answer!?

Comment: My mistake but i also came to know of that fact now... I seriously dont have an awk in my busybox config...@sudo_O

Comment: If a system has `sed` it is highly likely to have `awk` also.

Comment: It does not my friend..!!! To make the system light we have stripped of many things from our busybox config.(awk included)

Comment: Yes, it does! The system had `awk` and you removed it!!! That is not valid argument against my statement, ridiculous! **Yes I can be done with sed** and have implied it once, stated it once and you have an answer that does that job in `sed`!!!

Comment: Can you help me with that? @sudo_O

Answer (score 1):

If `date` command could work for a date handling, I would stand with `date` command.

```
kent$  date -d"Fri May 3 13:50:37 2013" +"%a%e %b %Y %T"                             │       %M     minute (00..59)
Fri 3 May 2013 13:50:37
```

Comment: I cannot stick with date due to our system constraints as it is an embedded system.The timestring which i have is in a c program which is obtained through ctime.So, how exactly can we do it with an awk or a sed.I plan to pass the string with the command itself i.e. in short if i have a string "1 2 3 4 5".How to use sed or awk such that sed -option command "1 2 3 4 5" so that output is "1 3 2 5 4".

Answer (score 1):

Use the back references in the regular expression and match the subpatterns.

```
sed -E 's/^(...) (...) ([0-9]+)(.*)([0-9]{4})$/\1 \3 \2 \5 \4/'
```

Comment: I am sorry to ask but i have no hard exp. with sed the only reason is that the linux which i have (on an embedded sys ) only supports sed.I am soory toa sk but how do you pass the argument.Please tell in both ways from the shell or a script.Sorry for the discomfort but really just do appreciate the help.Thnx

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) ([123]?[0-9]) /\2 \1 /g' file
```

Comment: Thanks but i also need to swap the last two words as well ,what can be done ,i might appear as foolish seriously i dont have much experience with awk but urgently need to implement this...!!The last two arguments namely time and year.?